# Evaluating expressions in Java using JEP

Tags: java, boolean

I am using [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) (Java expression parser) for a requirement. When there is a expression of the following format and the variables are replaced by numerical values, everything works smooth.

For eg:

```
String formula = "(A || B )" ;
JEP jep = new JEP();
jep.addVariable("A", -1.0);
jep.addVariable("B", 0.0);
jep.parseExpression(formula);
Number value = jep.getValue();
System.out.println("Value: " +value);


-----------------------------

Value : 0.0
```

But what when the value of A and B are booleans, eg (TRUE or FALSE) this fails. Could anyone suggest how JEP supports the boolean inputs scenario?

```
String formula = "(A || B )" ;
JEP jep = new JEP();
jep.addVariableAsObject("A", Boolean.TRUE); 
jep.addVariableAsObject("B", Boolean.TRUE); 

jep.parseExpression(formula);
Object val = jep.getValueAsObject();
System.out.println("Value: " +val); // gives null
```

Comment: What does "Fails" mean in this context? Does it fail to compile? Does it give an exception? If so what is the exception/error message?

Comment: I mean it fails to compile, I do not seem to get how to pass boolean values to the variable

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing the primitives `true`/`false` ? What are those variables `FALSE` and `TRUE` ?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/types.html) doesn't mention the boolean type, so it's probably not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are wrong, JEP Java supports boolean: http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/operators.html

I'm confused where did you found the functions addVariableAsObject, getValueAsObject? In the documentation they doesn't exist.

This works fine:

```
    String formula = "(A || B )" ;
    Jep jep = new Jep();
    try {
        jep.addVariable("A", Boolean.TRUE); 
        jep.addVariable("B", Boolean.TRUE);
        jep.parse(formula);
        Object result = jep.evaluate();
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    } catch (JepException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```